# Push Notification is not working in Xamarin Crossplatform

Tags: xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

MainActivity:

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(Intent);
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(intent);
    }
```

I added a Plugin.FirebasePushNotification and also included a google-service.json file into the Android.

In MainApllication OnCreate method:

```
FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, new NotificationUserCategory[]
        {
        new NotificationUserCategory("message", new List<NotificationUserAction> {
            new NotificationUserAction("Reply", "Reply", NotificationActionType.Foreground),
            new NotificationUserAction("Forward", "Forward", NotificationActionType.Foreground)

        }),
        new NotificationUserCategory("request", new List<NotificationUserAction> {
            new NotificationUserAction("Accept", "Accept", NotificationActionType.Default, "check"),
            new NotificationUserAction("Reject", "Reject", NotificationActionType.Default, "cancel")
        })

        }, true);
```

App.cs contains the following code:

```
  public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new SampleNotification.MainPage();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {           
       CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Subscribe("general");

        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += (s, p) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TOKEN REC: {p.Token}");
        };
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TOKEN: {CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Token}");
    }
```

Xaml.cs contains:

```
   public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();     

        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
        {
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received");
                if (p.Data.ContainsKey("body"))
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        textLabel.Text = $"{p.Data["body"]}";
                    });

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        };

        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += (s, p) =>
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(p.Identifier);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Opened");
            foreach (var data in p.Data)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{data.Key} : {data.Value}");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Identifier))
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    textLabel.Text = p.Identifier;
                });
            }
            else if (p.Data.ContainsKey("aps.alert.title"))
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    textLabel.Text = $"{p.Data["aps.alert.title"]}";
                });

            }
        };
    }
```

When request send from the Postman, receives data and it contains the Title and Message but I didn't get the notification in my device.
Please help me

Comment: Try running app in release mode, some times you will not get push notification received in debug mode if you run more than one time, if you want to debug run in debug mode try uninstalling the previous app.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, now it's working

Comment: I am receiving only one notification and if there is another notification comes, it replaces the previous one, is there any solution for this

Comment: Most likely this happens because you use the same notification id for all your notifications. Try to assign new id each time

Comment: currently Iam not assign any notification id, could you please mention where I initialize the id in my code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758061/getting-multiple-notification-instead-of-one-in-android

Comment: @Grisha This is not working in my code and Iam not using any class.., is there any other solution

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem, please answer me it's very urgent...